# How to feel the rhythm of a song

Tags: guitar, rhythm

I'm absolute beginner in guitar, I've watched this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Y6cYhvPoiLI&list=PLn8Cg_n-kuKAjz8DJwy-WAnue0NHBleSD&index=8)  and I want to know what he meant by "to feel the rhythm”. Is it about finding strumming pattern of a song?

Comment: Please add where the quote happens in the video so that answerers don't have to watch the entire thing looking for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When he speaks about feeling the rhythm he is not talking about something as complex as figuring out a strumming pattern. He is merely referring to trying to find the basic pulse of the music. A lot of music has a steady pulse or beat to it that even many non-musicians can recognize. Paraphrasing him, it is the steady beat you might feel causing you to tap your foot, nod your head, slap your knee, clap your hands or snap your fingers steadily along to the music. I’m sure you have heard audiences in a show either spontaneously or at the request of a performer begin to clap steadily along to the music. This is what he is talking about.

Comment: Thank you for explanation, for example about this  [song](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KhH-icsxMjE&ab_channel=RolfRattay),  I heard drum beat , should I strum down/up based  on drum beat ?

Comment: When he says on the video use all 4 fingers to mute, that's pretty important. Just using one may well produce harmonics rather than scratches. Answering your comment - yes, with the heaviest being a downstrum, and all others following that, in a pattern.

Comment: Spontaneous audience clapping! I forget who it was in concert, but the audience clapped on the 'wrong' beat, and the singer/pianist put a 5/4 in to get them in time! Ref youtube. (Harry Connick Jr - just found it...)

Comment: @Tim Yes, Harry Connick Jr. it was great, he instantly Hippified the audience, lol! I’ll try and find a link to the video.

Comment: @Tim here it is, around 0:40: https://youtu.be/UinRq_29jPk

Comment: @todo Regarding your question and song example in comments  I would begin by trying to identify the pulse of the song. This like the majority of songs is in 4/4 time which means the song is divided into 4 beat sections. Try and count 1-2-3-4 to the song and make those all down strums. After a while you can strum twice as fast down and up. You will be counting 1+2+3+4+. The numbers will be down strums a and the +’s will be up strums. The important thing is to be steady and match the feeling of the music. As you learn more you can start using strumming patterns and learn to play the chords too.

Comment: i struggled with this; listen to the bass drum with an occasional reference to chords. Turn down the treble, You wont always get a bass drum beat on beat 1; but you'll likely get on *a* beat. Then listen for the next one, and the next and if evenly spaced you're getting closer to the speed of the beats, or more likely half of it as bass drums often play on two of the four beats . Listen out for another  drum playing *between* those bass drum beats and youve likely heard a third and fourth beat if evenly spaced. Listen for chord changes to find beat 1. Quickly becomes second nature.

Comment: @bigbadmouse Yes, bass drums can be unsteady but some other cues are snare is usually on 2&4 (the clapping beats) and high hat or ride cymbal will often e playing fairly steady notes, either 2 or 4 to a beat (8th and 16th notes respectively). Don’t overanalyze or overthink it, just nod your head or tap your foot where it feels natural like the video says. The recognition and knowledge will come in time.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best way to experience rhythm is to put away the guitar first.

Listen to the song, let your body move, so you dance to it. It may be a simple leftFoot-rightFoot, or some wipping and snipping, or rotatingLeft - rotatingRight, whatever.

Let the song move you, literally, physically. (If it doesn't, try a different song.)

You should be able to identify the beginning of a beat ("1"), and the other beats, too. As many songs ar in 4/4 time signature, you should at least be able to hear beats "1", "2", "3", "4".

Once you've got that, it's time to return to the guitar. And yes, in the end it boils down to "hit strings at certain times". There are many ways to do it, like:

- picking, strumming, fingering
- try emphasizing 1, 2, 3, 4, or only 1, 3, or only 2, 4
- try emphasizing some off-beat, like 1, 2, 3,+, 4

and so on.

Whith this knowledge and experience listen again to songs, and discover, what they do, and the effect it has on music, sound, feel etc.